# Error IndexOutOfRangeException en método

Tags: c#

La linea `nombre[j] = nombre[j - 1];` me tira un error

> OutOfRangeException

```
    static bool elimino(int[] lista, string[] nombre, string nom, ref int tope) 
    {
        nom = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim();
        bool e = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < tope; i++)
        {
            if (nom == nombre[i])
            {
                for (int j = i; j < tope - 1; j++)
                {
                    lista[j] = lista[tope - 1];
                    nombre[j] = nombre[j - 1];
                    tope--;
                    e = true;
                    i = tope;
                }
            }
        }
        return e;
    }
```

Aquí llamo al método:

```
elimino(vector, nombre, nom,  ref  tope);
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa cuando `j` vale `0`?

Comment: deberia eliminarme las columnas cuando encuentra al jugador, deberia ser `j=0`?

Comment: Quiero decir, cuando `j` vale `0`, `j-1` vale `-1`. Y el índice de un array empieza a partir de `0`...

Comment: y entonces como lo soluciono?

Comment: Según el código `j` no debería ser `0` nunca. Comienza teniendo valor `1` y se va incrementando. Entiendo que el problema es que `tope` es mayor que la longitud del array `nombre` y en algún momento se intenta obtener un índice superior al número de elementos.
Pero para saber cómo solucionarlo habría que saber qué es lo que pretende hacer el método.

Comment: el metodo en teoria deberia encontrar el nombre solicitado y eliminar el array de nombre junto a las 5 columnas que es cada bolilla de una apuesta `cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] vector = new int[cantidad];
            nombre = new string[cantidad];
            int[,] matriz = new int[cantidad, 5];` esto lo tengo definido en el main, me pide una cantidad (filas de la matriz que es igual a la cantidad de nombres de apostantes y 5 columnas que son 5 numeros que elige), me deberia eliminar la apuesta

Comment: @AsierVillanueva En la primera iteración, `i = 0`, `j = i = 0` (`j` se inicializa a `i`, no a `1`)

Comment: Cierto. Perdón. Había leído mal el código. Me había parecido un `1` en lugar de `i`

Answer (score 1):

Aqui:

```
for (int j = i; j < tope - 1; j++)
{
      nombre[j] = nombre[j - 1];
}
```

Inicializas `j` con el valor de `i` que en la primera vuelva `i = 0` y entonces haces esto:

```
nombre[j - 1]
```

Donde `j - 1` es igual a `-1`.

Esto es lo que pasa paso por paso:

```
i = 0;
j = i;
x = j - 1;
x == -1;
```

Y en un array nunca existira un array con un indice `-1`. Por eso el `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: perfecto lo modifique asi > for (int j = i; j < tope - 1; j++)
>    ` {
>        lista[j] = lista[j + 1];
>        nombre[j] = nombre[j + 1];
>        tope--;
>        e = true;
>        i = tope;
>}` pero solo me elimina el usuario no su apuestas

Comment: Que bueno. Espero con ansias que nos enseñes como hiciste que elimine las apuestas.

Answer (score 0):

> OutOfRangeException

Esto ocurre cuando el índice esta fuera de rango del vector o matriz, por ejemplo un vector v[5] de tamaño 5 y que leas el valor en una posición < 0  ó  > 5

```
int i = v[-1]; // Error
```

dicho esto deberías inicializar j como i+1:

```
for (int j = i+1; j < tope - 1; j++)
```

Comment: Perfecto, gracias, pero no me esta eliminando, una vez que lo elimino, si vuelvo a listar, me sigue apareciendo el cliente  y su jugada

Comment: perfecto lo modifique asi > for (int j = i; j < tope - 1; j++) > ` { > lista[j] = lista[j + 1]; > nombre[j] = nombre[j + 1]; > tope--; > e = true; > i = tope; >}` pero solo me elimina el usuario no su apuestas

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo "lista" es un arreglo de números que se relaciona con "nombres"

Si tu idea es eliminar el objeto en la posición j, remplasandolo con el ultimo elemento de ambos arreglos, tu código deberia ser:

```
> for (int j = i; j < tope - 1; j++)
>     {
>        lista[j] = lista[j + 1];
>        nombre[j] = nombre[j + 1];
>        tope--;
>        e = true;
>        i = tope;
>}
```

de esta forma mantienes el relacionamiento lista-nombres

Pero para mejorar tu código podrias usar un Hash y usar foreach en vez de un for convencional, asi mejoras tu código y lo haces mas legible.

O usar lista.length en lugar de tope, no se si entendí lo que deseas hacer, además del código creo que deberías explicar que pretendes hacer con el para la proxima

Comment: correcto, pero ahi solo me elimino al usuario, no me elimino su jugada, por si sirve de algo yo en el main decalre asi la matriz, donde cantidad es la cantidad de usuarios, o sea filas (nombres) `cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] vector = new int[cantidad];
            nombre = new string[cantidad];
            int[,] matriz = new int[cantidad, 5];`